# How to break this Mail Method in two parts without breaking its functionality

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, email

[image]I have write a readFromSharedInbox() method. When I am checking the code with sonarLint i am getting this error "**Refractor this method to reduce its cognitive complexity**". So i want to break this method in two parts. But i am not able to do so.I am trying to create a method to read the mail from inbox.
My Code look like this

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Address;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Flags;
import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Part;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;
import javax.mail.internet.ContentType;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;
import javax.mail.search.ComparisonTerm;
import javax.mail.search.FlagTerm;
import javax.mail.search.ReceivedDateTerm;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Example;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class MailServiceImpl implements MailService {

    @Value("${mail.host}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${mail.id}")
    private String mailBoxId;

    @Value("${mail.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${mail.protocol}")
    private String protocol;

    @Value("${mail.socketfactory}")
    private String socketfactory;

    @Value("${mail.fallback}")
    private String fallback;

    @Value("${mail.port}")
    private String port;

    @Value("${mail.savepath}")
    private String savepath;

    @Value("${submission.fields}")
    private String fields;
    
    @Value("${mail.endidentifier}")
    private String mailEndIdentifier;
    
    @Autowired
    private EmailRequestRepository emailRequestRepository;

    @Autowired
    private CoreWorkflowService coreWorkflowService;

    public void readFromSharedInbox() { 
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", protocol);
        props.setProperty("mail.imaps.socketFactory.class", socketfactory);
        props.setProperty("mail.imaps.socketFactory.fallback", fallback);
        props.setProperty("mail.imaps.port", port);
        props.setProperty("mail.imaps.socketFactory.port", port);

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
        try {
            Store store = session.getStore(protocol);
            store.connect(host, mailBoxId, password);

            Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
            inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

            ReceivedDateTerm receivedDateTerm = new ReceivedDateTerm(ComparisonTerm.EQ, new Date());
            FlagTerm seenTerm = new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false);
            Message[] todaysMessages = inbox.search(receivedDateTerm);
            Message[] foundMessages = inbox.search(seenTerm, todaysMessages);

            List<EmailRequest> emailRequestList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < foundMessages.length; i++) {
                Message message = foundMessages[i];
                String subject = message.getSubject();
                String content = message.getContent().toString();
                String contentType = message.getContentType();
                Address[] froms = message.getFrom();
                String sender = froms == null ? null : ((InternetAddress) froms[0]).getAddress();
                Date recieveDate = message.getReceivedDate();

                // store attachment file name, separated by comma
                StringBuilder attachFiles=new StringBuilder();
                if (contentType.contains("multipart")) {
                    // content may contain attachments
                    MimeMultipart multiPart = (MimeMultipart) message.getContent();
                    content = getTextFromMimeMultipart(multiPart);

                    int numberOfParts = multiPart.getCount();
                    for (int partCount = 0; partCount < numberOfParts; partCount++) {
                        MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart) multiPart.getBodyPart(partCount);
                        if (Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(part.getDisposition())) {
                            // this part is attachment
                            String fileName = part.getFileName();
                            if (attachFiles.length() > 0) {
                                attachFiles.append(",");
                                attachFiles.append(fileName);
                            } else {
                                attachFiles.append(fileName);
                            }
                            System.out.println(fileName);
                        }
                    }
                    message.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(new File(savepath + sanitizeFileName(subject) + ".eml")));
                }
                System.out.println("Content type: " + contentType);
                EmailRequest emailRequest = EmailRequest.builder().emailRecieveDate(recieveDate).subjectEmail(subject)
                        .emailContent(content).fromEmail(sender).toEmail(mailBoxId).isMailProcessed(false).build();
                emailRequestList.add(emailRequest);
            }
            inbox.close(false);
            store.close();
            System.out.println("reading done!");
            emailRequestRepository.saveAll(emailRequestList);
            System.out.println("Email data saved successfully in db table");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private String sanitizeFileName(String subject) {
        return subject.replaceAll("[:\\\\/*?|<>]", "_");    
    }

    private String getTextFromMimeMultipart(MimeMultipart mimeMultipart) throws IOException, MessagingException {

        int count = mimeMultipart.getCount();
        if (count == 0)
            throw new MessagingException("Multipart with no body parts not supported.");
        boolean multipartAlt = new ContentType(mimeMultipart.getContentType()).match("multipart/alternative");
        if (multipartAlt)
            // alternatives appear in an order of increasing
            // faithfulness to the original content. Customize as req'd.
            return getTextFromBodyPart(mimeMultipart.getBodyPart(count - 1));
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            BodyPart bodyPart = mimeMultipart.getBodyPart(i);
            result.append(getTextFromBodyPart(bodyPart));
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

    private String getTextFromBodyPart(BodyPart bodyPart) throws IOException, MessagingException {

        String result = "";
        if (bodyPart.isMimeType("text/plain")) {
            result = (String) bodyPart.getContent();
        } else if (bodyPart.isMimeType("text/html")) {
            result = (String) bodyPart.getContent();
        } else if (bodyPart.getContent() instanceof MimeMultipart) {
            result = getTextFromMimeMultipart((MimeMultipart) bodyPart.getContent());
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void readMailDetailsFromDb() {
        EmailRequest email = new EmailRequest();
        email.setIsMailProcessed(false);
        Example<EmailRequest> whereClause = Example.of(email);
        List<EmailRequest> findAll = emailRequestRepository.findAll(whereClause);

        Map<String, Object> processVariables = null;
        for (EmailRequest emaeil : findAll) {
            System.out.println(emaeil.getSubjectEmail() + " : " + emaeil.getEmailId());
            processVariables = EmailParserUtil.parse(fields, emaeil.getEmailContent(), mailEndIdentifier);
            // workflow service
            try {
                Workflow startWorkflow = coreWorkflowService.startWorkflow(Constants.SUBMISSION_PROCESS_ID, Constants.MAIL, processVariables);
                startWorkflow.toString();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // update mail
            emaeil.setMailProcessedOn(LocalDateTime.now() )  ;
            emaeil.setIsMailProcessed(true)  ;
            emailRequestRepository.save(emaeil) ;
            
            
        }

    }

}
```

This is MailService Class

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

public interface MailService {
    public void readFromSharedInbox(); 
    public void readMailDetailsFromDb() throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException;
}
```

Comment: You need to explain what exactly you are having trouble with.

Comment: @tgdavies when i checked my code using sonarQube it shows that SonarQube Refactor this method to reduce its Cognitive Complexity for readFromSharedInbox() method.

Comment: And what aspect of the refactoring are you having trouble with?

Comment: i have attached a photo in my question this is what i am getting. I only just want to make method smaller and simpler but also do not want to lose the functionality.

Comment: Firstly you can move the props.setProperty statements into a separate method and directly get Properties object. Then you can move the For loop in which you are iterating over Multipart into a Separate method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your IDE for things like that.

You select a part of your code, right click on it and refactor it by extracting the code in a new private method.

For exemple, you can do this on the "for" statement.

Or the "if (contentType.contains("multipart"))" part with a manageMultipart method.